# Active Directory for Web apps

Tags: authentication, architecture

We are in process of building a web application for our customers (consumers) only. I am just wondering what is the use of storing user credentials in Active Directory? We can just stored encrypted credentials in database as well, right?

Background:  We use Active Directory for our internal web applications where users are employees only.

Please let me know if I missed anything here?

Answer (score 0):

AD will provide you a nice replicated credential/attribute store. If you're not otherwise planning to use AD and don't see a use for the replication functionality, I'd stick with a simple database store.